# How to install PsCyr on Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: installing, mac

I downloaded "PSCyr-0.4-beta9-tex.tar.gz" and "PSCyr-0.4-beta9-type1.tar.gz" archives but I don't know what I should do with it. In google I don't found guide for installing this on mac os x.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you download them from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is to use the Terminal.

1. Create a working directory and move there the two archives
2. Open a Terminal window and `cd` to the created directory
3. Uncompress the two files with

   ```
   tar zxf PSCyr-0.4-beta9-tex.tar.gz
   tar zxf PSCyr-0.4-beta9-type1.tar.gz
   ```
4. Do `cd PSCyr`
5. Do `cp install.sh install-tl.sh`
6. Open the `install-tl.sh` file with a text editor and modify it so that it contains

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   INSTALLDIR=`kpsewhich -expand-var='$TEXMFLOCAL'`
   mkdir -p $INSTALLDIR/{tex/latex,fonts/tfm/public,fonts/vf/public,fonts/type1/public,fonts/map/dvips,fonts/afm/public,doc/fonts}/pscyr
   mv dvips/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/fonts/map/dvips/pscyr
   mv tex/latex/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/tex/latex/pscyr
   mv fonts/tfm/public/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/fonts/tfm/public/pscyr
   mv fonts/vf/public/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/fonts/vf/public/pscyr
   mv fonts/type1/public/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/fonts/type1/public/pscyr
   mv fonts/afm/public/pscyr/* $INSTALLDIR/fonts/afm/public/pscyr
   mv LICENSE doc/README.koi doc/PROBLEMS ChangeLog $INSTALLDIR/doc/fonts/pscyr

   mktexlsr

   echo "Map pscyr.map\n" >> $INSTALLDIR/web2c/updmap.cfg
   updmap-sys
   ```

   <sub>There are a few lines to remove and `TEXMF` should be changed into `INSTALLDIR` (setting `TEXMF` could confuse the system); also `TEXMFMAIN` *must* be changed into `TEXMFLOCAL`. You can also just remove all the contents and paste the code above.</sub>
7. Do `sudo sh install-tl.sh` (type the administrator password when requested)
8. Enjoy.

I created the following test file, using http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/_russian

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{pscyr}

\begin{document}

Ан шэа пльакырат такематыш жямиляквюы, лебыр дёжкэрэ лобортис эю кюм, ан квюо агам вокябюч 
жплэндидэ. Брутэ дектаж ыт нык, мэнтётюм квюаырэндум шэа ат, экз нык зюаз долорюм. Вэл экз 
коммюны аппарэат инкедыринт, жят экз ажжюм аликвюип фэюгаят. Еюж ку дёжкэрэ тебиквюэ, 
ножтрюд льюкяльиюч хаж ад, йн мэль порро кхоро рыпримёквуы. Иреуры нонюмэш ючю ку, ат мыа 
экшырки эквюедым.

Йн витаэ пырикюлёз про. Фюйзчыт витюпэраторебуз вэл эю, мюкиуж такематыш йн квюо. Хаж эрат 
еллум граэкы ад, ед про пошжим рыпримёквуы эффякиантур. Элитр ёнвидюнт волютпат еюж но, 
кхоро пльакырат эож но, убяквюэ ыёрмод но ыам. Мэль нэ вирйз мэнтётюм ажжынтиор, ёнэрмйщ 
чингюльищ нэ шэа, квуй ан оффекйяж дытракжйт прёнкипыз. Кашы фырре алььтэрюм ку еюж.

\end{document}
```

Here's the output

[image]

Comment: After installation latex don't makes pdf but dvi creates without error (as I think :D). If I'll comment `\usepackage{pscyr}` then all work properly. This is log of PSCyr installation: http://pastebin.com/jwzhmnVG

Comment: @0x1337 The `pscyr.map` file, together with `t2a.enc` and `t2d.enc` might have been saved in the wrong directory. I realize now that there was a small error in the file (I fixed it in my own setting and forgot to fix it also in my answer). The line starting with `mv dvips/pscyr/*` has to be fixed as it's now. You can remedy manually by doing `sudo mkdir /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/maps/dvips/pscyr` and `sudo mv /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/dvips/pscyr/* /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/maps/dvips/pscyr`. Then run `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: I done it. But also I have errors... http://pastebin.com/jDdVCTGq My install-tl.sh - http://pastebin.com/xxb6vWYR

Comment: @0x1337 I don't know where I have my head. `;-)` Running `sudo mktexlsr` should be done before `sudo updmap-sys`. Sorry.